# Display timer while Audio Recording in Android

Tags: android, timer

I am new in Android. I want to make one Audio Recording application. In that when I Click on start button then in textView I want to display timer. For example, I want to display like this way:- 1.20 or 2.30...

Can any one help me for displaying timer?

I know this is not a big question but I dont understand the concept of timer in the way I want to used in my application.

Please guide me anybody.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this purpose try Android [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) Class, Its much more simpler than inventing your own

A very basic example is given [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-chronometer.html)

Comment: Hey can you tell me how to play our recorded audio on the button click? My recorded file stored in sdcard and in that one folder will generted "Audio Recording". I want to play that audio on my Play button click. Can you suggest me that is there any way to play audio file without using mediaPlayer? Please help me.. Thanks.

Comment: Without mediaPlayer its not possible

Comment: Ok. So how can we fetch data from sdcard path and play that? I tried but not working properly. Thanks.

Comment: yeah we can do that but post it as another question or this thread will be spammed by moderators

Comment: Hey how to display reverse counter when user playing audio using  Chronometer? like 0.5, 0.4 , 0.3 .... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**you can use CountDownTimer for this ::**

```
  CountDownTimer cntr_aCounter = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

         // recodeing code 
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            //finish action
        }
        };cntr_aCounter.start();
```